# Wrong email subject but with the correct content

Tags: professionalism, email

I sent an email asking for clarification of a problem, to a university. The university provides a subject format that must be followed by email senders. 
The format is something like this:

```
[id - name : problem]
```

Because my ID is quite long, I copied the subject from my previous email that had a different problem. So I just sent an email with the wrong subject, what should I do? Do I need to resend with the correct subject?

Comment: I thought workplace stack exchange was a place for asking about "professionalism". I consider universities to be companies where they have the same ethical rules

Comment: No mention was made of whether the OP is staff, student, contractor, in a sales role - I think this is a reasonable question of how to correctly communication in a professional setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would resend with the correct problem but add a note that you have made a mistake previously.

If you have a contact perhaps them as well to explain your mistake.

Most people accept a genuine mistake. We are human and make mistakes from time to time.

Comment: You mean 'correct problem' I think, the ID is correct.